# Retrieving XSLT code as string - "Illegal characters in path"

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, xslt, xslt-1.0

I want to transform a XML document. My XSLT code is working and it transform correctly (tested in XMLPad), but now I want to make it transformed in my VB.NET program. 
The thing is that I don't want to load the XSLT code from `.xsl` file. I have it hard-coded in a function, but I am getting `Illegal characters in path` exception.

Is it possible to have it like that:

```
Public Class xsltTransformCode
    Public Function transformationXSLTcode() As String
        Return "<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' version='1.0'>" &
        "<xsl:strip-space elements='*'/>" &
        "<xsl:output method='xml' indent='yes'/>" &
        "<xsl:key name='AreaByPosition' match='Area' use='Position'/>" &
        "<xsl:template match='@*|node()'>" &
            "<xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select='@*|node()'/></xsl:copy>" &
          "</xsl:template>" &
            "<!-- for the first Area in each Position -->" &
          "<xsl:template match='Area[generate-id() = generate-id(key('AreaByPosition', Position)[1])]'>" &
            "<Area>" &
              "<!-- copy in the Position element once only -->" &
              "<xsl:apply-templates select='Position'/>" &
              "<!-- copy in all sub-elements except Position from all matching Areas -->" &
              "<xsl:apply-templates select='key('AreaByPosition', Position)/*[not(self::Position)]'/>" &
            "</Area>" &
          "</xsl:template>" &
            "<!-- ignore all other Area elements -->" &
          "<xsl:template match='Area'/>" &
        "</xsl:stylesheet>"
    End Function
End Class
```

because I get the exception when I try to load it

```
Dim xsltTransformerCode As New xsltTransformCode()
Dim xsltTransCompiled As New XslCompiledTransform()
xsltTransCompiled.Load(xsltTransformerCode.transformationXSLTcode())
```

Answer (score 2):

I Just looked on MSDN to confirm by suspicion, and it verifies that you can't pass the actual XML string to the XslCompiledTransform.Load function. The string versions of this require a URI, hence the complaint about "bad characters in path".

You can however load the XML using an XMLReader:

```
Dim xsltTransformerCode As New xsltTransformCode()
Dim sr as new System.IO.StringReader(xsltTransformerCode.transformationXSLTcode())
Dim xr as XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(sr)
Dim xsltTransCompiled As New XslCompiledTransform()
xsltTransCompiled.Load(xr)
```

This was hastily converted from some c# code, I'm sure that you can tinker with it if it doesn't work as is.

Mark

Comment: Good catch; needs to be combined with the broken quotes fix, too

Comment: And don't forget to close all your readers and streams and things :)

Comment: nah, if you need to close them you're doing it wrong... `using(...)`

Comment: Yes, I use using in C#, didn't know that it was the same in VB, what I mean is, don't just let them go out of scope, that's lazy and doesn't always clean up properly.

Comment: Yep, this time it works. 
Now I am getting `XSLT compile error` exception when loading it `xsltTransCompiled.Load(xr)`. 

But that is a mistake in the string itself. The thing is that I tried AGAIN changing the xml attributes to have double-quotes with escape character before them and also tried changing all the single-quotes to double-quotes with escape chars. 
No change... I guess I will have to find out how to represent the content of the `.xsl` document as string.

Comment: @Syspect if it is using standard xml reading, it will probably tell you where the xml error is. Heck, just do something like `File.WriteAllText "foo.xsl", xsltTransformerCode.transformationXSLTcode()` and then open `foo.xsl` in the IDE to see what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Look at the combination of single-quotes for things like:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select='key('AreaByPosition', Position)/*[not(self::Position)]'/>
```

I would advise using double quotes for the xml attributes, and single-quotes for literals; since this is part of a VB string, this will involve doubling the double-quotes to *escape* them, i.e.

```
"<xsl:apply-templates select=""key('AreaByPosition', Position)/*[not(self::Position)]""/>" &
```

(multiple locations etc, not just this one line)

Comment: I tried this (changing the xml attributes to have double-quotes with *escape* character before them) and also changing all the single-quotes to double-quotes with *escape* chars, but still the same problem occurs.

Comment: @Syspect oh, right - yeah you need to combine this with the `XmlReader` in Mark Rabjohn's answer. 2 sets of errors in one piece of code ;p

Answer (score 0):

You have this `match` attribute

```
match='Area[generate-id() = generate-id(key('AreaByPosition', Position)[1])]'
```

which contains a single-quoted string within a single-quoted string.

Unfortunately you can't do that, and you will have to escape the inner quotes. I'm afraid I don;t know how to do that in VB.

Answer (score 0):

For example following line is not correct escaped:

```
"<xsl:template match='Area[generate-id() = generate-id(key('AreaByPosition', Position)[1])]'>"
```

From xslt point of view you have to use apostrophe and quote as delimiter. If the attribute delimiter is apostrophe  you have to use quotation mark as delimiter  for const (liek your key name `AreaByPosition`.

```
<xsl:template match='Area[generate-id() = generate-id(key("AreaByPosition", Position[1])]'>"
```

But this does not work form visual basic point of view. You have to escape the quotation mark.
Therefore try:

```
   "<xsl:template match='Area[generate-id() = generate-id(key(\"AreaByPosition\", Position)[1])]'>"
```

But I'm not sure about esacping in visual basic